# How to chain promises in different swift classes using PromiseKit?

Tags: ios, swift, promise

In a class named `Support` we have a function named `loadURL` returning `Promise<String>`

A function in another class named `A` invoked `support.loadURL` in a promise way:

```
support.loadURL(url: url).then{ result in
        print(result);
    }.catch{error in
        print(error);
    }    
}
```

But this function was invoked by another function in class `B`, so here, the function in B want to do more with the Promise. How can I deal with it?

In short, `B.b` called `A.a`, `A.a` called `support.loadURL()` in a Promise Way. Can `B.b` do the promise chaining?

I tried to wrap `A.a` in to a promise:

```
return Promise{ fulfill, reject in
    support.loadURL(url: url).then{ result -> Void in
            print(result);
        }.catch{error -> Void in
            print(error);
        }    
    }
}
```

But always leads to warning:

```
PromiseKit: Pending Promise deallocated! This is usually a bug
```

Comment: i think you can use `DispatchGroup()` if you want to wait for one async function response before calling another async function

Comment: @VarunNaharia Sounds like a solution. I can also using completeHandler to  get this done. But I wonder whether there is a way to keep the elegancy of Promise...

Comment: Never used Promise, so it's hard to find solution with that for me

Comment: please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Define dispatch group in appdelegate

`let myGroup = DispatchGroup()`

Then

```
AppDelegate.sharedelegate.myGroup.enter()
support.loadURL(url: url).then{ result in
        print(result);
        AppDelegate.sharedelegate.myGroup.leave()
    }.catch{error in
        print(error);
        AppDelegate.sharedelegate.myGroup.leave()
    }    
}
```

In other class

```
AppDelegate.sharedelegate.myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
//do your work when other is done
}
```

Or You can try this with promise

```
return Promise{ fulfill, reject in
    support.loadURL(url: url).then{ result -> Void in
            print(result);
            fullfill(result);
        }.catch{error -> Void in
            print(error);
            fullfill(error);
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your closure neither called `fulfill` or `reject` thus indeed, it would be deallocated without resolution: you didn't resolve it.

However, the real solution is not to use `Promise{ fulfill, reject in` at all, and just `return support.loadURL(url: url)`. You were wrapping a promise in another promise.